# Link app name or a text to app Link in google play market

Tags: android, google-play

I have a share button in my app,Instead of sending app link `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>` via intent  `ACTION_SEND` I want to link, app link in play store  to a text(app name).so receiver will see a name and by clicking on that will be redirect to app in play store.How can I achive that?

```
     SpannableString s = new SpannableString("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={packageName}");

                    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
                    String messStr = "Check out this event: " + eventObj.getString(Configs.EVENTS_TITLE) + " | from #AppName "+"\n"+s +"\n";
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) eImg.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    Uri uri = getImageUri(EventDetails.this, bitmap);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messStr);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share on..."));
```

Comment: I'm confused, do you want a deep link to your app?

Comment: No We don't.we want sth like hyperlink in html

Comment: I see. You need to use something like linkify. But your question isn't phrases well. The button opens the browser/play store to the app URI , is that true?

Comment: the button send a sentences includes app name..when the user click app name redirects to platy store app URI

Comment: Just posted an answer. if it doesn't work, please don't downvote, just comment and I'll fix it.

Comment: Ok Man I will let you know tnx for help

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, I don't believe you can do that reliably. You don't really have any control over how any other app chooses to handle or display the data you pass to it. If you pass text in a certain format - e.g., as a URL, as you have it there - then some apps, like SMS apps, will parse that, and linkify it themselves, but you can't dictate how it's displayed. You could possibly try sending HTML, but, there again, who knows how the receiving app will choose to handle it.

Comment: I would also point out that, in your example, `messStr` is just a flat `String`, since `s` is having `toString()` implicitly called on it, so none of the formatting is retained.

Comment: @MikeM. Dear Mike thanks for your help on this ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Version: User change the package name**

You have the button, and can set the text to whatever you want, then you set the onClick method with intent to the play store

```
///You need to set an EditText attribute in your layout, similar to how you set the button 
packageName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit); 
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id); 
//locates button from xml layout file

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Tries to open the play store to your listing 
     String str = packagename.getText().toString();

 try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + str)));
    } 
  catch (ActivityNotFoundException e1) 
   { 
//catches error if play store isn't found
        Toast.makeText(this, "Play Store not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 } 
 });
```

This should work in theory.

Comment: I didn't mean text on the button.I mean instead of http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={pakagename} ...the user whom shared with (receiver)..see app name by clicking on app name redirects to http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={pakagename}

Comment: @HadiSamadbin try it now